# Split a column based on Upper and lower case

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that have a column where values are like that:

### A

```
FOO          Foo

DOE          John 

UPPER        Lower

VAN MECKELEN Maria
```

I want to split it into two columns **where fully upper strings are into the first one and string on the other column**

```
B            |       C
-------------------------
FOO          |Foo

DOE          |John

UPPER        |Lower

VAN MECKELEN |Maria
```

Is there any simple way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out:
The query is,

```
Select
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(A, '[[:upper:]]+[[:space:]]{0,1}[[:upper:]]+') as B,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(A, '[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+') as C,
From MY_TABLE
```

Comment: It also includes the first capital letter of the consecutive word. Is that okay?
Also it is not working when there are more than 3 capital letter words. when your column has values like,
'VAN MECKELEN EFGD Mari'
'ABCE EFG DFC'

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned above, the above regex you have provided will not work for all kind of inputs. So, changed the regex accordingly by testing with few different inputs.
You can use the below query if that is your need.

```
with t as (
        select 'FOO Foo' as coln from dual
        union 
        select 'UPPER Lower' from dual
        union
        select 'VAN MECKELEN EFGD Mari' from dual
        union
        select 'ABCE EFG DFC' from dual
        union
        select 'abcef' from dual
        )
        Select   coln, 
regexp_replace(regexp_substr(coln, '([A-Z]+[[:space:]]*)+'), '[[:space:]][A-Z]$') as B,
regexp_substr(coln, '([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+[[:space:]]*|[[:lower:]]+)+') as C
From t;
```

Comment: Fails with : VAN MECKELEN EFGD Mari Antoinette

Comment: Edited accordingly

Comment: B return exactly the same as coln.

Comment: @Cromm For what value?

Comment: For the whole block of records of your example, I just tried it on sql developers.

Comment: If there is no string with lower case chars then it will just return the upper case words as such. For other values it will work as expected

Comment: I got it: 
`regexp_replace(regexp_substr(coln, '([A-Z]+[[:space:]]*)+'), '[[:space:]][A-Z][a-z]+$') as B,
regexp_substr(coln, '([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+[[:space:]]*|[[:lower:]]+)+') as C`
[a-z]+ was missing